# How can I generate 30 random fractions and print them on different lines?

Tags: java, random, fractions

I am writing in Java Swing doing a homework problem where I have to print 30 random fractions with one on each line of a text file. I should do this using a function.

I am not sure what the best way to do it.

I know I could create many hundreds of lines to do this but I want to make my work much shorter.

```
public static int printer() throws IOException{
    FileWriter fileOutStream = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Auden\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\FractionGame\\src\\fractiongame\\equations");
    PrintWriter fileOutput = new PrintWriter (fileOutStream);
    int ran;

    ran = getRandomNumber();
    fileOutput.print(ran+"/");
    ran = getRandomNumber();
    fileOutput.print(ran);
    fileOutput.println("");  
    fileOutput.close();
    return ran;
}
```

I don't know how to use this to create multiple fractions on different lines.

Comment: How is this related to Swing?

Comment: i do  not see swing.

Comment: You have to look for "for" : https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_for_loop.asp

Comment: "*I am not sure what the best way to do it.*" - You are learning. Do not look for the best way. Get it working. Then (and only then!) make it good.

Comment: Obviously you want a loop. But is there a specification about the range of denominator? Should it be a proper fraction with numerator less than denominator?

Comment: So an example of a line in the file you are writing would be `2/3`, right? What about `2/1`? And what about `0/7`?

Comment: **AND** what about `7/0`. That would also be a possible, but not valid, value!

Answer (score 0):

```
    IntStream.range(0, 30)
            .mapToDouble(i -> Math.random())
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Just replace console with file print